# Public list variable is empty

Tags: list, static, variable-names, empty, public

I have a class with 3 methods (1 static and 2 normal) - A,B,C methods.  B is the static method.  A calls B method, B calls C method.  There is master list variable which is updated in C method.

In C method, the list size is 1. But I check the list size in method A (in the same transaction), the size is 0.  WHY? How can I get the master list value in method A.

```
public List<String> MasterList = new List<String>();

public void methodA(){
  staticMethodB();
  debug master list size-->0

}

public static void staticMethodB(){
  methodC();
}

public void methodC(){
   //do something;
   MasterList.add(xx);
   debug master list size-->1
}
```

Comment: Can you call non-static `methodC()` from static `staticMethodB()` without a class instance?

Comment: Yes, I instantiate the class again in staticMethodB and call method C;

Comment: Oops!in that case there will be two separate contexts and the `MasterList` will have separate values for them.This is interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are moving from static context to non-static context and that's what is causing the problem.

The code above is incomplete. I presume that you are just giving an idea above, as you justify it by saying that you are instantiating the class in staticMethodB i.e. you are creating a new instance. Hence, any previous value set in MasterList is no longer available as within staticMethodB, there is a new instance of methodC.

If you want to share the MasterList across all instances, then declare MasterList as static.

Otherwise, pass the instance of class to static method and from there to calling methods, so that same class instance can be passed and used in all methods.

Comment: Yes, i get it.  I just made the masterList as static.  that worked! Cheers!